# How can I make the sound stop when the button is clicked and the image is gone?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that starts off with the imaged is displayed when it is loaded without the music playing.

When the button is pressed the first time the image disappears. When it is pressed the second time the image appears and the music plays.

This happens every time, except the music is supposed to stop and set back to the beginning when the button is clicked so the image disappears, and then restarts when the image appears.

Can someone help me out please and tell me how to make the sound stop?

This is what I have: (I left out some unnecessary code regarding position etc.)

```
<button id="b" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Here To Enter The Show!</button>
    <script>

    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById('myDIV')
        var snd = new Audio("ann.mp3");
        var sond = new Audio("hearpeoplesing.mp3");
        if (x.style.display === 'none') {
            x.style.display = 'block';
            snd.play();
            sond.play();
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    </script>
    <div id="myDIV">
    <img src="ticket.png" alt="Ticket" width="300" height="200">
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is showImg called and why is your script not in one script tag?

Comment: Oh sorry showImg() was from something else I'll delete it off the question